# Axios GET requests return empty promises to html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, async-await

I have tried to make this work all day long, and I have no idea what is happening.

I have this html table using vue v-for (I reduced the code to make it clearer):

```
<table id="timeSheet-datatable" class="table table-striped dt-responsive w-100">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(timeSheet,index) in timeSheetListPageable">
        <td>{{getProjectById(timeSheet.projectId)}}</td>
    </tr>                                                   
</tbody>
```

and I have this js:

```
async getProjectByIds(param){

   var result = '';
   await axios
       .get(`/project/${param}`).then(response => {
             result= response.data.name;
         }, response => {
             (err) => console.log(err)
         });
   return await result;
},


getProjectById(param){

   const data = this.getProjectByIds(param);

   console.log(data)
   return data;

},
```

The problem is that I don't know why the return is not working, the table results are empty spaces, and if I add async and await to `getProjectById` method the return is `[object Promise]`.

The `console.log` inside the `getProjectById` works property, it shows the correct returns from the Axios, but the return to the table doesn't work. I already tried to change a lot of things in this code, any suggestions?

Comment: There is no `then` on an `await`ed function. You need to do `var result = await axios.get(...)`

Comment: Thank you for answering. Ahh ok, but how the axios would be then ? I tried to do it, but the return was `[object Promise]`

Comment: Do not call getProjectById from the template. Data is supposed to be retrieved in mounted hook.

Answer (score 1):

`await result` after `axios.then()` construct will not result in the expected sequential flow.

You need to use either promises or multiple `await` statements to make the code readable and execute properly.

```
async getProjectByIds(param){

    var result = '';
    try {
        var response = await axios.get(`/project/${param}`)
        result = response.data.name;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
    return result;
},


async getProjectById(param){

    const data = await this.getProjectByIds(param);

    console.log(data)
    return data;

},
```

I am not sure about the actual `response.data` statement. You may or maynot have to use an `await` there.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I just tried with your code, and the `console.log` shows the values correctly, but the return to html table on frontend shows `[object Promise]`

Comment: You would have to see how to load `async` components in vue. Ref: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Comment: "construct will not result in the expected sequential flow" - it will. The code is ugly but this is not a reason why it doesn't work as intended.